# LSTM Cell backpropagation through time & independence of gates

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, backpropagation

I am calculating the backpropagation across LSTM cell gates, and I notice that many online sources treat the gates as independent. For example, in [this Aidan Gomez blog](https://blog.aidangomez.ca/2016/04/17/Backpropogating-an-LSTM-A-Numerical-Example/), he derives the backpropagation update for weight $W_a$ using $\delta a_1$:

$\delta a = \delta state \cdot i \cdot $ tanh'$(a)$

Presumably, he derives the $i_1$ term by assuming that $\frac{d}{da} (i \cdot f(a)) = i \cdot \frac{d}{da} f(a)$, which necessitates that a and i are independent.

However, $i_1$ is a function of $out_0$, which is itself a function of $a_0$. In this manner, would we not have to consider $\frac{d}{da}(i)$ when updating the weight matrix $W_a$?

In other words, the weights $W_a$ affect the state output at all times $t$, so any term which depends on state $H_{t-1}$ then must also have some dependency on $\Delta W_a$, right?

The same logic applies to all of the other weight matrices and their interdependencies.

---

I've tried to work out some of the implications of this below. Hopefully you can follow the long usage of the chain rule here.

Let $E$ be the error function we are using for gradient descent. Suppose we are calculating the update for weight matrix $W_A$ of the input activation gate. Note that the linked example uses explicit sigmoid and tanh functions, but I will use general notation $f_k$ for gate $k$ activation function.

$\frac{\delta E}{\delta W_A} = \frac{\delta E}{\delta H_t} \frac{\delta H_t}{\delta W_A} $, where $H_t = o_t * f_S(S_t)$.

$ \frac{\delta H_t}{\delta W_A} = \frac{\delta o_t}{\delta W_A} f_S(S_t) + o_t f_S ' (S_t) \frac{\delta S_t}{\delta W_A}$ using product rule on $H_t$.

Note that $o_t = f_o (W_o X_t + U_o H_{t-1})$. Let us call $W_o X_t + U_o H_{t-1} = Z_o$ for easy reference. Then,

$ \frac{\delta o_t}{\delta W_A} = f_o ' (Z_o) * U_o * \frac{\delta H_{t-1}}{\delta W_A} $,

The complication here is that the previous output $H_{t-1}$ also has some dependency on $W_A$. **This is the crux of the problem!!!** If we assume independence between gates, this would cancel out nicely to zero, but that doesn't seem mathematically sound.

Now expanding this term in the previous derivation, we get

$ \frac{\delta H_t}{\delta W_A} = \bigg( f_o ' (Z_o) * U_o * \frac{\delta H_{t-1}}{\delta W_A} \bigg) * f_S(S_t) + o_t f_S ' (S_t) \frac{\delta S_t}{\delta W_A}$

which requires the calculation of $\frac{\delta S_t}{\delta W_A}$, where $S_t = a_t * i_t + f_t * S_{t-1}$.

$\frac{\delta S_t}{\delta W_A} = \frac{\delta a_t}{\delta W_A} * i_t + a_t * \frac{\delta i_t}{\delta W_A} + \frac{\delta S_{t-1}}{\delta W_A} * f_t + S_{t-1} * \frac{\delta f_t}{\delta W_A}$ by using the product rule a bunch of times. Solving each term:

$\frac{\delta a_t}{\delta W_A} = X_t + U_A \frac{\delta H_{t-1}}{\delta W_A}$

$\frac{\delta i_t}{\delta W_A} = U_i * \frac{\delta H_{t-1}}{\delta W_A}$

$\frac{\delta f_t}{\delta W_A} = U_f * \frac{\delta H_{t-1}}{\delta W_A}$

From here, $\frac{\delta S_{t-1}}{\delta W_A}$ and $\frac{\delta H_{t-1}}{\delta W_A}$ are now circular, since we're currently trying to figure out those same terms for time $t$.

I'm banging my head against a wall here. If all the cross-gate terms truly cancel out, then the math is easy. I'm just not seeing justification for why they cancel out. Any help is appreciated!

---

The only explanation I can think of is that $H_{t-1}$ is considered a "fixed" input, such that we don't consider backpropagation through that channel. This seems like a cop-out though, as $H_{t-1}$ is certainly an adjustable quantity in terms of the various weight matrices. Anybody have further insight on this?

Comment: Quite similar to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/273460/215801).

Comment: @OrenMilman Thank you for the link! That is precisely my question, although it seems that neither that page - nor the linked Reddit and Quora threads - seem to answer the question very well. The Reddit page has an answer that seemingly says "we ignore this for convenience and call it 'truncated brackpropagation' " - which is obviously unsatisfying :p . Especially given that truncated bptt is already a thing that refers to only going back K time steps, nothing to do with actual propagation of the gradient through gate terms.

Comment: To me it also feels unsatisfying, though I am not an expert (and maybe we both just missed something here).